# Unable to select table row by clicking on ui component inside a column of table in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I'm creating a web application using Vaadin Framework, but have got stuck with a table element(Filter table). My table has a column which contains ComboBox component in each row, now the combobox in the table works properly, but I can't click on that column to select the table value.The row can be selected in the table by clicking the space between combobox and column boundary  BUT can not be selected by clicking on the combobox itself. 
 I searched a lot and found https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/988648/988647 , tried implementing blackboard addon, but was unsuccessful. My code is roughly below.

```
PagedFilterTable<IndexedContainer> filterTable;
     `public static PagedFilterTable<IndexedContainer> buildPagedFilterTable()
         {
                    filterTable = new PagedFilterTable<IndexedContainer>();
                    filterTable.setFilterBarVisible(true);
                    filterTable.setSelectable(true);
                    filterTable.setImmediate(true);
                    filterTable.setMultiSelect(true);
                    filterTable.setRowHeaderMode(RowHeaderMode.INDEX);
                    filterTable.setColumnCollapsingAllowed(true);
                    filterTable.setContainerDataSource(buildContainer());
                    filterTable.setVisibleColumns((Object[]) new String[] {
                            "Clear", "Name" });
                    return filterTable;
                }` 
          static int f=1;
                private static Container buildContainer() {
                    IndexedContainer cont = new IndexedContainer();


                    cont.addContainerProperty("Clear", Component.class, null);// added combobox component
                    cont.addContainerProperty("Name", String.class, null);


                    //populating table with database values (table rows will be = no. of rows in db)
                    Connection con;
                    ResultSet rs;
                    Statement cs;   
                    try {

                        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","CGoracle");
                        cs=con.createStatement();
                        co=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
                        rs = cs.executeQuery("select * from ECS_CURRENT");  
                        while(rs.next())
                        {

                             ComboBox select_reason_return=new ComboBox();          
                            select_reason_return.setInputPrompt("Select");
                            select_reason_return.setVisible(true);
                            select_reason_return.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
                            select_reason_return.setInvalidAllowed(false);
                            select_reason_return.addItem("1.A/c Closed/Transfered");
                            select_reason_return.addItem("2.No Such A/c");
                            select_reason_return.addItem("3.Clear");

                            select_reason_return.select("3.Clear");
                            select_reason_return.addListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {


                                @Override
                                public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {

                                    String reason=select_reason_return.getValue().toString();
                            rowId=FilterTable.getValue();
                            Notification.show("row id is ="+rowId);
            }
                        });

                             cont.addItem(f);

                                cont.getContainerProperty(f, "Clear").setValue(select_reason_return);
                                cont.getContainerProperty(f, "Name").setValue(rs.getString(10));

                            f++;

                        }

                    } 
                    catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 

                    return cont; 
              }
```

[If it helps, I'm posting screenshots, Image 1: if I select anywhere other than the combobox, it is returning row id properly.Image 2: Though I'm selecting an item from combobox, table row is not getting seleced, hence it's not returning me row id.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTUW0.jpg)
Is there any option other than blackboard addon? If no, then please help me to solve this problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

Is not the best approach, but, you can do it by: placing a Listener on the ComboBox to know when it gets clicked. Then, in this event you get the row associated with the ComboBox, to finally get id associated to that row.

Once you have the row Id use the Table.select() method, to select the item row.

It is not the best approach and if you have many rows you will feel how it gets a slow response, but is the only programmatic way I've found to get it working. Hope it helps.

Comment: I've implemented your suggested method in the code above, but it's returning me row Id as null, have attached screenshots above to show the same.